# Fullcalendar batchRendering for setOption doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, ajax, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I need to make two changes to the fullcalendar dynamically. See below:

```
        calendar.setOption('hiddenDays', hiddenDays);
        calendar.setOption('businessHours', businessHours);
```

It worked, but for each "setOption" fullcalendar makes a request to the server!

I tried it that way, but it also didn't work:

```
    calendar.batchRendering(function () {
        calendar.setOption('hiddenDays', hiddenDays);
        calendar.setOption('businessHours', businessHours);
    })
```

Is there any way to make all the changes and then send the request?

Comment: "for each "setOption" fullcalendar makes a request to the server!".... not by default it doesn't. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/gOpWObN . Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem - i.e., enough code and data so that we can actually run it and see how the problem is happening. You can fork my CodePen if you like, and change it so that we would be able to see these requests to the server  happening. Otherwise we cannot help you. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for answering!
On here: https://codepen.io/acsar/pen/eYNRmPX?editors=1111  A similar issue reported: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/3923

Comment: Ok well it looks like the bug is specific to when you have a custom events function. And it looks like there are 2 or three similar bug reports online already. So if you haven't already, you should add your comments and votes to them. That's how to get it resolved. There's nothing anyone on StackOverflow can really do to fix the bugs. As far as I know no-one here is a fullCalendar developer - we just answer questions about how to use it.